# Transplanting local branches from one repo to another

Tags: git

There was a git repo `R`, which was split by cloning several other repos (let's call them `R1`, `R2`...`RN`, or `RX` for any of them) from it and deleting different stuff in those repos. For new projects, these new repos are about to replace `R`. Old projects will either ported to the clones or stick with `R`. If someone makes a late fix to `R`, they can push it to our central repo and it can from there be merged into the appropriate clone(s).

However, in the local clone of `R` on my disk, I have a couple of branches that contain private experiments which I do not want to lose, but which I do not want to push to central either.

Is there a way for me to merge these branches into the respective `RX` clone without having to push them to central first?

Assume I can rebase all those branches onto the latest `master` in `R`, and that the clones are up to date regarding their `R`'s `master`.

Comment: use the `--mirror` option when pushing to your new remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got this working by making my local clone of `R` a remote for my local clone of the `RX` repository I want to transplant a branch to. When in the targeted repository `RX`, in git bash on Windows, this does the trick:

`git remote add local_R file:///c/path/to/R`

Within `RX`, I can now fetch from `local_R`, check out `R`'s branches, merge them into `RX`'s branches, etc.

Comment: This sounds good, but while you're naming one of the repos `R`, you are naming the other one _my local clone of the clone I want to transplant a branch_. Why not giving another letter for readability?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant